# Mutex Threading - Code doesn't seem to Exit Properly

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

So I have code here which makes two kinds of threads. One kind "produces" data and the other one "consumes" it. There can only be a certain amount of data that can exist at any one time, so the Producers will pause producing once there is a certain amount of data created (ie, when sharedData = BUFFER), and the consumers will pause when sharedData = 0. There is also only so much data that can be made (amount stored in dataleft), and once all the data has been made and consumed, the program should end.

For some reason, the printf() lines I have at the end of the code don't seem to ever trigger. I can't tell if the threads are closed properly or not because of this. It feels like I've done something really stupid, but I can't see the issue.

A couple of definitions at the start:

```
#define                 NUMCONSUMERS    4
#define                 NUMPRODUCERS    4
#define                 PACKETS         10
#define                 tryMainlock     pthread_mutex_trylock(&dataMutex)
#define                 openMainlock    pthread_mutex_lock(&dataMutex)
#define                 closeMainlock   pthread_mutex_unlock(&dataMutex)
#define                 waitMainlock    pthread_cond_wait(&dataPresentCondition, &dataMutex);
#define                 signalMainlock  pthread_cond_signal(&dataPresentCondition);

#define                 trydatalock     pthread_mutex_trylock(&IsthereDataleft)
#define                 opendatalock    pthread_mutex_lock(&IsthereDataleft)
#define                 closedatalock   pthread_mutex_unlock(&IsthereDataleft)

pthread_mutex_t         dataMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t          dataPresentCondition = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t         IsthereDataleft = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int                     sharedData=0;   //amount of data present
int                     BUFFER = 5;
int                     dataleft=PACKETS;
```

The Main Function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int rc;                                 
int i;
pthread_t  consumer[NUMCONSUMERS];
pthread_t  producer[NUMPRODUCERS];

rc = opendatalock;                      //lock to determine whether there's any point waiting for data

for (i=0; i <NUMPRODUCERS; i++) {       //Build up the producers
    rc = pthread_create(&producer[i], NULL, Producer, (void *)i);
    if (rc)
        printf("Error building Producer Thread: %x\n", i);
}

for (i=0; i <NUMCONSUMERS; i++) {       //Build up the consumers
    rc = pthread_create(&consumer[i], NULL, Consumer, (void *)i);
    if (rc)
        printf("Error building Consumer Thread: %x\n", i);
}

printf("All Producers and Consumers created\n");

for (i=0; i <NUMPRODUCERS; i++) {       //Join up the producers
    rc = pthread_join(producer[i], NULL);
    if (rc)
        printf("Error: Producer %x: Failed to join\n", i);
}

rc = closedatalock;                     //producers finished, no data left to make

printf("datalock closed, consumers finishing...\n");
for (i=0; i <NUMCONSUMERS; i++) {       //Join up the consumers
    rc = pthread_join(consumer[i], NULL);
    if (rc)
        printf("Error: Consumer %x: Failed to join\n", i);
}
rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&dataMutex);
rc = pthread_cond_destroy(&dataPresentCondition);
rc = pthread_mutex_destroy(&IsthereDataleft);

printf("All Threads finished. Exiting....\n");
return 0;
}
```

The Consumer Thread:

```
void *Consumer(void *threadid){
int rc;
printf("Consumer Thread %x: Created\n", (int)threadid);
while (1)
{
    printf("Consumer %x: Entering Loop\n", (int)threadid);
    rc = openMainlock;      //take hold of main lock
    if (rc)
    {
        printf("Consumer %x: Waiting...\n", (int)threadid);
        rc = waitMainlock;  //if main lock is taken, wait
        if (rc)             //if wait fails, exit the thread.
        {
            printf("Consumer Thread %x: wait for Main Lock failed\n", threadid);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    while (sharedData == 0) //if the buffer is empty
    {
        rc = trydatalock;
        if (!rc)
        {
            printf("Consumer %x: Completed. Exiting...\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        rc = closeMainlock;
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
        rc = waitMainlock;
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
    }
    sharedData--;
    rc = closeMainlock;
    rc = signalMainlock;
    if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
    printf("Consumer %x: Releasing Lock\n", (int)threadid);         
}
}
```

And the Producer Thread:

```
void *Producer(void *threadid){
int rc;
printf("Producer Thread %x: Created\n", (int)threadid);
while (1)
{
    printf("Producer %x: Entering Loop\n", (int)threadid);
    rc = openMainlock;          //take hold of the lock
    if (rc)                     //if lock is currently being used by a consumer or a producer
    {   
        printf("Producer %x: Waiting...\n", (int)threadid);
        rc = waitMainlock;      //wait here until lock is released
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("Producer Thread %x: wait for Main Lock failed\n", threadid);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    if (!dataleft)              //If there's no data left to add to the stream, close the thread
    {
        printf("Producer Thread %x: Completed, exiting...\n", (int)threadid);
        exit(0);
    }
    while (sharedData >=BUFFER)
    {
        rc = closeMainlock;
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
        rc = waitMainlock;
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
    }
    printf("Producer %x: Lock Acquired\n", (int)threadid);
    sharedData++;
    dataleft--;
    rc = closeMainlock;
    rc = signalMainlock;
    if (rc)
        {
            printf("code.\n");
        }
    printf("Producer %x: Releasing Lock\n", (int)threadid);
}
}
```

Comment: Can it be that you are using a simple `int` as mutex? That's not going to work, check out the `pthread_mutex...` functions. Also, what are `waitMainlock` and `closeMainlock`? Those are missing from your code, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: oh wait, damn. I defined a couple of bits at the start, I'll add them in. the mutex function returns an int. It returns 0 when the function executes properly, ie, it took the lock.

Comment: Ouch. Those macros are highly misleading. If you used ALL_UPPERCASE, it would at least have been obvious that those are macros. That said, if you want to avoid typing those function calls, use subroutines that lock the mutex, check the returnvalue and exit on failure. That way, the main functions wouldn't be cluttered by the errorhandling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this piece of code:

```
    if (!rc)
    {
        printf("Consumer %x: Completed. Exiting...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
```

If the consumer has finished, the process(!) is terminated. You need to use pthread_exit() instead, or simply return from the thread function.

Then, there is also

```
../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:80:
    __pthread_mutex_lock: Assertion `mutex->__data.__owner == 0' failed.
```

which I got a few times running the code. That could be caused by e.g. double unlock or some other invalid use. I'd start with cleaning up the weird macros, so that you have a free view on the logic of the program itself.

Also, one important advise concerning mutexes: Always document precisely which data should be protected by the mutex. The point is that it's not always clear and getting this wrong means that you accidentally access data without synchronization. In order to make this very clear, use a structure like here:

```
 struct {
     pthread_mutex_t mutex;
     pthread_cond_t cond;
     int data;
 } synced_data = {
     PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
     PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
     0
 };
```

Actually, it's not just about the shared data that documentation is important. Consider for example `IsthereDataleft`: This is a mutex but it doesn't guard anything, right? Instead, it is used to signal to the started threads that there is nothing left to do, right? Documenting this not only helps others to understand your code but it makes sure that you understand yourself what the intention is. Sometimes, while trying to explain it, you will then find yourself that something doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Something seems to be awry with your use of `openMainlock`, which expands to a `pthread_mutex_lock` call.

One one hand, you shouldn't expect to ever get a non-zero return value from `openMainlock`: `pthread_mutex_lock` should either return zero (lock acquired) or block, unless the mutex is not initialised or is an error-checking mutex.

Further, once the lock is acquired, if the producer is done, i.e. `dataleft` is zero, the thread calls `exit(0)`, which will terminate the whole process rather than terminating the thread. `pthread_exit` should be used instead, or just return from the function, but note that at this point you still own the main lock, which won't be released.